# List the names of sheets which have a specific string

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook that contains multiple sheets. On each sheet, Column A lists all the assets related to that sheet. I want to do two things:

1. Create one sheet which has a list of **all** the assets captured from *each* individual sheet and remove any duplicate(s); and
2. Develop a process/macro to get a list of **all** sheet names where a particular asset shows up.

For example, if I select a particular Asset (e.g. `abc`), I should get a list of all the sheets of which this asset is a part.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i was able to generate a list of all the sheetnames using either a macro, but i am unable to filet that list based on presence of a string - this is my first time dabbling in Excel - so unfortunately i have not gotten too far.

Comment: Maybe you could come back and [edit] your question to show your own effort after you've dabbled some more and have a specific programming question.

Comment: Take a look at the Power Query Add-in from Microsoft for Excel.